# El expression doubt

Tags: java, jsp

in EL expression in JSP we can use `${"1"+"2"}` but not `${"Dark"+"Knight"}`. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [JSP 2.1 (2006) spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/index.html) defines `+` as an arithmetic operator only, so it cannot be used for string concatenation. `"1"` and `"2"` are coerced to numerical types according to the rules for coercion, so `${"1"+"2"}` will evaluate to `3`.

Comment: You're truly amazing, Mr. McDowell!